# Manually assign existing object to Entity Framework navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to manually assign an existing object to an Entity Framework (db first) object's navigation property?

The context to the question is that I have a problem in trying to bring back a (heavily filtered) list of objects with all the children and descendants attached so that the full graph is available in memory after the context is disposed.

I tried doing this via `.Include()` statements using something like this:

```
  using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
  {
    myParents = ctx.Parents
        .Where(p => MyFilter(p))
        .Include(p => p.Children)
        .Include(p => p.Children.Select(c=>c.Grandchildren))
        .Include(p => p.Children.Select(c=>c.Grandchildren.Select(g=>g.GreatGrandChildren)));

  }
```

but the generated query runs too slowly because of the known performance problems with using nested include statements (as explained in lots of places including [this blog](http://mikee.se/Archive.aspx/Details/entity_framework_pitfalls,_include_20140101)).

I can pull back the parents, children and Grandchildren without performance issues - I only hit the troubles when I include the very last `.Include()` statement for the greatgrandchildren.

I can easily get the GreatGrandChildren objects back from the database with a second separate query by building a list of GrandChildrenIds from the GrandChildren already retrieved and doing something like:

```
greatGrandKids = ctx.GreatGrandChildren.Where(g=>ids.Contains(g.GrandChildId)).ToList();
```

but now, once I dispose of the context, I cannot do something like `grandChildA.GreatGrandChildren` without hitting the object context disposed exception.

I could have as many as a few thousand GrandChildren objects so I really want to avoid a round trip to the database to fetch the GreatGrandChildren for each one which rules out simply using `.Load()` on each GrandChild object, right?

I could feasibly work around this by either just looking up the required greatgrandchildren from `greatGrandKids` each time I needed them in my subsequent code or even by adding a new (non-mapped) Property such as `.GreatGrandChildrenLocal` to the `GrandChild` class and assigning them all up front but these both feel **very** kludgy & ugly. I'd MUCH prefer to find a way to just be able to access the existing `.GreatGrandChildren` navigation property on each `GrandChild` object.

Trying the obvious of assigning to the navigation property with something like this:

```
grandchild.GreatGrandChildren = greatGrandKids
    .Where(g=>g.GrandChildId == grandChild.Id)
    .ToList();
```

fails too when I then try to access `grandchild.GreatGrandChildren` (still giving the object disposed exception).

So my question is:

**Is there a way I can assign the existing GreatGrandChdildren objects I have already retrieved from the database to the `.GreatGrandChdildren` navigation property on the GrandChild object in such a way as to make them available (only needed for read operations) after the context is disposed?**

(Or indeed is there a different solution to the problem?)

Comment: What kind of application are you using? Web? WinForms? Usually, you would not have to do such operations after the context is disposed. What if you use `Select` to only select the necessary properties? Then, if you need to insert a new child object, you can do this without loading its parents, only using the correct ids. Show an example of the code you are using

Comment: @FabioLuz This is for a backend service. It cannot be so uncommon to need to access descendant properties after the context is disposed? I need those descendant properties to perform some operations using the associated data. I need every single one 'GreatGrandChildren' objects associated with the filtered parents (there are only a couple of parents after the filter) to perform those operations so suggesting a `.Select()` doesn't get around hitting the database several thousand times I am afraid. I'd like to avoid doing that if I can.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got it wrong. It would be easier if you provide some example code, including where you are getting the exception

Comment: @FabioLuz I understand the object disposed exception fully. It, in and of itself, isn't the problem I am trying to describe however, to answer your comment as fully as I can - if you were to remove the final include statement in my minimal example above then try `var x = parents.First().Children.First().Grandchildren.First().GreatGrandChildren` after the `using` block then the object disposed exception would appear on that line. I avoided including my actual code as it contains some 'cruft' not relevant to the problem I am trying to describe. I have attempted to reduce it to a minimal example.

Comment: Are your Children, GrandChildren and GreatGrandChildren of the same type? Not that it's very important, but might give us a small hint. Also does this whole structure have static depth, or does it increase with time?

Comment: @raderick No, the Parents,Children,Grandchildren and GreatGrandchildren are each different types and this will always have the same depth - I will only ever want to bring back descendants up to GreatGrandChildren. A `GreatGrandChild` object doesn't have any further descendant objects I need in this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable proxy creation with:

```
ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

then reading and writing from/to the navigation property works exactly as expected without trying to lazily load the entities and throwing the object disposed exception.

So we have something like:

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    myParents = ctx.Parents
       .Where(p => MyFilter(p))
       .Include(p => p.Children)
       .Include(p => p.Children.Select(c=>c.Grandchildren));
       //skip the final GreatGrandChildren include statement

    //get the associated grandchildren & their ids:
    var grandKids = myParents.SelectMany(p=>p.Children)
        .SelectMany(c=>c.Grandchildren)
        .ToList();
    var ids = grandKids.Select(g=>g.Id)).ToList();

    //Get the great grandkids:
    var greatGrandKids = ctx.GreatGrandChildren
        .Where(g=>ids.Contains(g.GrandChildId)).ToList();

    //Assign the greatgrandchildren to the grandchildren:
    foreach (grandChild in grandKids)
    {
        grandChild.GreatGrandChildren = greatGrandKids
            .Where(g=>g.GrandChildId == grandChild.Id)
            .ToList();
    }

 }
```

and now we can access the the `.GreatGrandChildren` property outside the context without hitting the context disposed exception. Whilst this still feels a little messy, it works out MUCH cheaper than either using the original `Include()` statement or calling `.Load()` on each GrandChild.

N.B. As these objects are only used in read operations and I don't need Lazy Loading then there are no negative implications to turning off proxy creation in my circumstances. If write operations and/or lazy loading were also necessary then we would also need to consider the implications of turning this off for the given EF context.